# UpdatePackage API Amazon Elastic Search not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, ansible, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to update a package via [UpdatePackage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-configuration-api.html#es-configuration-api-actions-updatepackage) api. I can give more details as per requirement.

Payload

```sh
{
  "PackageID": "myid",
  "PackageDescription": "New synonym file.",
  "CommitMessage": "Added some synonyms.",
  "PackageSource": {
    "S3BucketName": "my-backup-bucket",
    "S3Key": "my/synonyms.txt"
  }
}
```

Request in ansible

```yaml
- name: POST Request to register the snapshot repository
  uri:
    url: "{{ elasticsearch_url_ireland }}:/packages/update"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ lookup('file','roles/docker-elasticsearch-synonyms/templates/update_package.json') }}"
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    status_code: 201
  register: register_request_response
```

I get the following response after the API call

```sh
 access_control_allow_origin: '*'
  connection: close
  content_length: '177'
  content_type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  cookies: {}
  cookies_string: ''
  date: Tue, 01 Jun 2021 14:35:24 GMT
  elapsed: 1
  json:
    _id: someid
    _index: packages
    _primary_term: 1
    _seq_no: 0
    _shards:
      failed: 0
      successful: 1
      total: 2
    _type: update
    _version: 1
    result: created
  msg: OK (177 bytes)
  redirected: true
  status: 201
  url: https://myhost.es.amazonaws.com:/packages/update
```

Basically i want to do the following via API what I do using console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We finally used AWS SDK to solve the problem. We can get the same functionality using the following command

```sh
aws es update-package --package-id 1234567 --package-source S3BucketName=mybucket,S3Key=somefolder/synonyms.txt --region someregion
```

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/es/update-package.html)